# Example for Recurrence-OnlyOnWeeks using google calendar?

Tags: google-apps-script, rfc2445, rfc5545

I'm pretty new to `Google-Apps-Script`. Could you give an example how to use

> Calendar > Recurrence > [onlyOnWeeks](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_recurrence#onlyOnWeeks)

I want to create a daily event, but only in *three specific weeks*. My solution does not to work correctly. Daily events are creating but for every week.

```
var myrecurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence()
                          .addDailyRule().onlyOnWeeks([44,45,51]);
cal.createEventSeries(mytitle, startTime, endTime, myrecurrence);
```

Comment: Perhaps you could make an attempt at this yourself and then post here if you encounter problems and ask for help with a specific issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CalendarApp API behind the scenes uses the iCal specification. Per the specification, the "onlyOnWeeks" rule can only be applied with yearly rules.

More here - http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt

Search for "BYWEEKNO" and find the second instance for the specific rule there.

So try this line below and I think you'll get closer. Notice the "addYearlyRule" instead of "addDailyRule"

```
var myrecurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addYearlyRule().onlyOnWeeks([44,45,51]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the background information. It explains why the code is not working as expected. Thank you !

Comment: Great. Please "accept" the answer so that this thread will be helpful to folks in the future.